# ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation sql variables evaluation

Tags: activerecord

I'm stuck in a very strange problem. Im my project I use 'load_and_authorize_resource' in order to retreive information from database. 
Speaking more precisely, I have ItemsController and action #index. In this action, I have an instance variable @items of class ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation. If I pass any params to action index (for example, array of IDs), it will be merged automatically to this variable. But! @items.to_sql returns following:

```
SELECT "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."user_id" = $1
```

So, some of my code just ain't wroking due to this strange variable in a query - "$1". What I need is to replace this variable with a real value that came from params. Of course, I've found a solution (hack):

```
@items.where_values.each{ |node| node.right = params[:user_id] if node.left.name = 'user_id' }
```

But actually I don't want to do such a hack. Maybe you folks know how to replace $1 with a params[:user_id]? Thanks you in advance.

Controller code:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :items

  def index
    ArchiveWorker.archivate(@items)
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you share some controller code?

Comment: Controller code is too long, so I've added "light" version of it. Don't know if it could help.

Comment: Can you post your accessible_by? The error must be in there.

Comment: Also any default scopes you might be using on the Item model.